# IntelliJ IDEA - Create class on demand

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA, I wonder if this feature exists.

Let's say you are writing a piece of code in a Java Rest Controller. You realize that you haven't yet created a certain Bean that has to be returned in your current method.

But you just go ahead and write the code as if it existed. Just like:

```
@GetMapping("/my-bean")
public MyBean getMyBean(){

    return new MyBean("My Message");
}
```

The class MyBean doesn't exist yet.

In Eclipse, you just go Ctrl+1 --> Create Class MyBean. It automatically launches a little wizard to create the class saving a little bit of time.

Is this possible in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Alt-Enter -> create class MyBean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt enter or hit the red lightbulb